# Checking to make sure argv[1] is an integer c++

Tags: c++, integer, argv, argc

For my program I have to make sure the user only inputs a positive INTEGER.   for example if the user inputted 12hi it should not run the program and print to std error.  I am not quite sure how to implement this.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])   
{ 
    if(atoi(argv[1]) < 1)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR!"<< endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with your current implementation? If so, tell us how your implementation differs from your requirements.

Comment: `atoi` isn't sophisticated enough to give the right answer here. Look at `strtol`.

Comment: This only checks if it is a positive number so far, i cant find a way to check if it is an integer, for example:  if you recieved 28 from argv, main should return 0   but if you recieved 28abc, main should return false.

Comment: You need to check the value of `argc` before you even *think* about examining `argv[1]`. Consider what happens if you run your program with no arguments. And you're missing at least a couple of required `#include` directives.

Comment: i just didnt include them all, argc is already checked and good and all of the #includes are in the .h file

Answer (score 6):

Pass it to a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and ensure all data was processed:

```
if (a_argc > 1)
{
    std::istringstream in(a_argv[1]);
    int i;
    if (in >> i && in.eof())
    {
        std::cout << "Valid integer\n";
    }
}
```

See online demo at http://ideone.com/8bEYJq.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my revised answer.  sscanf wasn't behaving how I thought it would and strtol provides the best C-like solution that is very portable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  for (int i=1; i < argc; i++){
      char* end;
      long val = strtol(argv[i], &end, 10);
      if (argc >= 2 && !end[0] && val >= 0){
          printf("%s is valid\n", argv[i]);
      } else {
          printf("%s is invalid\n", argv[i]);
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:
  ./a.out 10 -1 32 1000 f -12347 +4 --10 10rubbish

```
10 is valid
-1 is valid
32 is valid
1000 is valid
f is invalid
-12347 is valid
+4 is invalid
--10 is invalid
10rubbish is invalid
```

This works because strtol will convert the argument to a long int. Then if end[0] is not at the end of the string it will be non-zero meaning it'll throw up an error for 10rubbish but be ok for values like 10.  Then of course we only want positive integers and I've included the value 0 in that set.

**atoi()** by itself is not good enough as it returns zero for failure. 0 could be a valid input.

**sscanf()** also by itself is not good enough because it'll successfully convert strings like 10rubbish and return the value 10.

I realise op only wants argv[1], this answer scans through all provided args just to show the output of lots of valid and invalid entries.

Comment: Without a format specifier `%` on the `"u"`, this isn't libel to to much.

Comment: strtol will work fine, since you pass a pointer to a pointer it will stuff with the end of the passed info.  Confirm that is the end of the string.  "     If endptr is not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first invalid
     character in *endptr.  If there were no digits at all, however, strtol()
     stores the original value of str in *endptr.  (Thus, if *str is not `\0'
     but **endptr is `\0' on return, the entire string was valid.)"

Comment: err true, I haven't used strtol for a very long time. Fixed the missing % - oops.

Comment: The solution does not allow the program to detect negative integer arguments, which the OP wishes to reject. A negative integer argument will be accepted and converted to unsigned, e.g. "-12567" will give `val` = 4294954729

Answer (score 1):

Since you evidently do not object to using the Standard C library,
the function

```
long strtol (const char* str, char** endptr, int base)
```

from `<cstdlib>` is quite sufficient to ensure that the
commandline argument is a (long) integer numeral with an optional
"-" or "+" prefix, and nothing more than that. You merely need to
check that the `char *` stored at `endptr` on return addresses '\0',
which tells you that the function has consumed the entire argument.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])   
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    char * endp;
    long i = strtol(argv[1],&endp,10);
    if (!*endp) {
        cout << "The value of \"" << argv[1] << "\" is " << i << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cerr << "\"" << argv[1] << "\" is not an integer" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

**LATER** ...or catering for Steve Jessop's comments:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])   
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    char * endp;
    long i = strtol(argv[1],&endp,10);

    if (*endp) {
        cerr << "\"" << argv[1] << "\" is not an integer :(" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (endp == argv[1]) {
        cerr << "Empty string passed :(" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (i < 0) {
        cerr << "Negative " << i << " passed :(" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (i <= INT_MAX) {
        cout << "Non-negative int " << i << " passed :)" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Non-negative long " << i << " passed :)" << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

A wrapper function would be in order for this degree of discrimination. And there
remains the very-very corner case that an input of `ULONG_MAX` will be accepted
as `LONG_MAX`.

Comment: +1, but there's one error which is that you haven't correctly handled the case where `argv[1]` points to an empty string. There's also a possible improvement, that you might want to print a different message in the case where the input string represents a value out of range of `long`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking if all the characters in `argv[1]` are digits (possibly with a leading minus sign). The check can be performed by using the standard library function `isdigit()`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/

Complete solution based on OP's actual code (also available at http://codepad.org/SUzcfZYp):

```
#include <stdio.h>          // printf()
#include <stdlib.h>         // atoi()
#include <ctype.h>          // isdigit()

int main(int argc, char *argv[])   
{ 
    if( argc != 2 ) {
        return 0;
    }

    char * pWord = argv[ 1 ];
    char c = 0;
    for( int i = 0; c = pWord[ i ], c ; ++i ) {
        if( ! isdigit( c ) ) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    int argvNum = atoi( argv[ 1 ] );
    printf( "argc = %d, argv[ 1 ] = %s, argvNum = %d\n",
        argc, argv[ 1 ], argvNum );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to C++ so please don't flame me if this is wrong, but couldn't you throw an exception and allow the user to re-correct the input?

I've learned a few ways of dealing with errors:

1. If/Else handling
2. Assert
3. Throw exception

1.IF/ELSE
    #include

```
int main(int argc, int **argv) {
    if (!isdigit(argv[1])) {
        // handle code if it's not a digit.
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is probably the easiest way to make sure

---

2.ASSERT
    #include

```
int main(int argc, int *argv[]) {
    assert(isdigit(argv[1]));
}
```

### * Assert will terminate the program if argv[1] is not a digit

3.THROW
    #include

```
using namespace std;

class Except {};

int main(int argc, int **argv) {
    try {
        isdigit(argv[1]);
        throw Except();
        // this code will not be executed
        // if argv[1] is not a digit
    }
    catch (Except) {
        cout << "argv[1] is not a digit.";
        // handle exception or rethrow
    } 
}
```

It is definitely worth noting that **throwing an exception will create a stack trace** and also all code in-between the thrown exception and the block that catches the exception will NOT be executed.

Comment: isdigit works at the character not char array level. So isdigit(argv[1]) doesn't do what you think if it even compiles.