# Converting Input string to float/double C++

Tags: c++, string, double

So I know how to do it in C#, but not C++. I am trying to parse giver user input into a double (to do math with later), but I am new to C++ and am having trouble. Help?

C#

```
 public static class parse
        {
            public static double StringToInt(string s)
            {
                double line = 0;
                while (!double.TryParse(s, out line))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
                    Console.WriteLine("[The value you entered was not a number!]");
                    s = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                double x = Convert.ToDouble(s);
                return x;
            }
        }
```

C++ 
?
?
?
?

Comment: [atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012571/stdstring-to-float-or-double

Comment: Not exactly the same question but the method is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181630/how-to-check-stdstring-if-its-indeed-an-integer/16181759#16181759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at atof. Note that atof takes cstrings, not the string class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> // atof

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    cout << "enter number: ";
    cin >> input;
    double result;
    result = atof(input.c_str());
    cout << "You entered " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/

Answer (score 1):

```
std::stringstream s(std::string("3.1415927"));
double d;
s >> d;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simplified version of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181630/how-to-check-stdstring-if-its-indeed-an-integer/16181759#16181759) which was for converting to an `int` using `std::istringstream`:

```
std::istringstream i("123.45");
double x ;
i >> x ;
```

You can also use [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof):

```
std::cout << std::strtod( "123.45", NULL ) << std::endl ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`atof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/):

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string foo("123.2");
    double num = 0;

    num = atof(foo.c_str());
    cout << num;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123.2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str;
...
float fl;
stringstream strs;
strs<<str;
strs>>fl;
```

this converts the string to float.
you can use any datatype in place of float so that string will be converted to that datatype. you can even write a generic function which converts string to specific datatype.